# How to get a Cisco VPN 3000 config as text?

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn

We would like to get a Cisco VPN device 3000 series configuration as a text file to look at the actual configuration, but apparently the interface is not a CLI but a graphical interface or menu driven.

Is there a way to get access to the complete config as a text?
And to copy and paste it to a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the complete text file used for configuration within the GUI (Administration/File Management) by cliking VIEW in the actions cloumn of the file you want to view. Have a look at the file named CONFIG ;)

Comment: I believe this is a snapshot of the interface: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/i/000001-100000/65001-70000/67001-68000/67563.jpg

Answer (score 0):

a Cisco VPN 3000 concentrator can also be accessed using telnet/telnet-over-SSL ; you can viwe the entire config from there (as is explained in the config guide 
  http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn3000/vpn3000_47/configuration/guide/cfg.pdf
)

HTH,

JJK

Comment: @janjust thanks for the link to the document. I am going through it right now... Could you point me to the specific paragraph I should look at?